# jgGrid customized add new form

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

When I open a blank form to add new row to the grid, I need some fields on the form to be dynamically updated by going to the database to search for data if I change a field on the form.

I found the code in the javascript to create a form for adding new row, may I change it to read from an external file (like an asp, php page) or is there any way to do it properly??

Answer (score 0):

You must use ajax to make calls to proper functions and change your html according to response data.

[More info about ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) supports ajax and have many nice features for [ajax usage](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and let you have nice page alteration based on html DOM. So i advice you to have a look at it...